# Having a StreamReader running makes the application unresponsive

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, streamreader, irc

I have a bot which connects to an IRC channel and reads the chat with a StreamReader. Everything works fine, the bot can read and response, but the problem is the Windows Form is freezing while the StreamReader is active.

```
while(true)
{
    string message = irc.readMessage();
    if (message.Contains("!test"))
    {
        irc.sentChatMessage("answer");
    }
}
```

I tried putting it on a timer instead of the while loop that ticks every 100ms with no change.

the method

```
public string readMessage()
    {
        string message = inputStream.ReadLine();
        return message;
    }
```

Comment: `ReadLine` blocks till it gets a full line, what do you expect it to do when you call it and it does not have a full line yet? You likely need to put it on a background thread or use `ReadLineAsync()` but we can't give you a full example of how to do it unless you show us more of where the `while(true)` loop lives

Comment: The method `readMessage()` blocks the UI thread. I'm not sure what stream you are using but if available you could use an async overload? Alternatively, you could run the method on a separate thread. This will prevent the `inputStream.ReadLine();` from blocking the UI thread.

Comment: @Scott Chamberlain the while(true) loop is active as soon as I connect the bot via the Windows Form and is supposed to be active for the entire time. I want to retain functionality of the form, so I can for example close the application.

Comment: Then get a `BackgroundWorker` put the code in that, if "closing the form" also closes the program the bot will stop. You will need to find a tutorial on how to do something like putting your app in the tray icons to not "really close"

Comment: @FlorianSchaal could you give me an example on how to run a method on a seperate thread?

Comment: @Gruhlum If there is a ReadLineAsync overload use it like this: `string message = await inputStream.ReadLineAsync ();` the method should then look like this: `public async Task<string > readMessage(){...}`. There are some samples on async here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx

Comment: I see there is an async  overload to StreamReader.ReadLine. I will put a full sample in an answer for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because `inputStream.ReadLine();` is blocking the UI Thread. If you use the async overload `StreamReader.ReadLineAsync` this will run asynchronously and therefore not block the UI thread.

**Sample:**

```
async void StartBot()
{
  while(true)
  {
    string message = await irc.readMessageAsync();
    if (message.Contains("!test"))
    {
        irc.sentChatMessage("answer");
    }
  }
}

public async Task<string> readMessageAsync()
{
   string message = await inputStream.ReadLineAsync();
   return message;
}
```

You can find more information aswell as samples about async and await [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt674882.aspx).

Comment: thanks, I got it working with your code, I only needed to add the while(true) loop again.

Comment: @Gruhlum yw, I have edited the answer to include the while loop.